# whether $\int_2^{\pi/2}\log\sin x \,dx$ proper or improper

Tags: improper-integrals

My book suggests $$\int_2^{\pi/2}\log\sin x \,dx$$ is an improper integral. But I think it is not for it is bounded on the respective interval....am I correct?

Comment: It is strange since $\sin x$ is strictly positive for $x \in [\frac{\pi}{2};2]$.

Comment: may be the lower limit is 0 not 2, for then it would be improper

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\ln\sin x~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\ln\cos x~dx~=-\frac\pi2~\ln2.~$